Generating an ISO image with genisoimage but it's not perserving the ownership?
Generating an ISO image with genisoimage but it's not perserving the ownership, I am using the following command genisoimage -r -v -o <image-name.iso> -R -J <path_to_the_directory>, but it just changed the ownership of files as root when I mount the iso.
